# Jlist updation giving me random results

Tags: java

I am working on creating a LAN messenger. I have a Jlist that is used to contain the list of all the online users over the LAN. The problem that I am facing is that whenever I login to the client, sometimes the list doesnt get updated. This problem is entirely random as in , it can happen the list is not updated when you have logged in for the first time or it may happen on the 10th occurrence. there is no fixed point at which it happens.

any help as to why this is happening would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I am doing the falling whenever a user disconnects/connects:

```
DefaultListModel.removeAllElements();  
writeUsers();
```

the writeUser() does the following:

```
String[] tempList = new String[(userList.size())];
userList.toArray(tempList);
for (String token:tempList) 
{
    DefaultListModel.addElement(token);
}
```

Comment: no one can help you just by reading what your app should do

Comment: have added some code snippets. hope it helps. Let me know if more is needed.

Comment: no the tempList is not empty. when I print userList.size() it doesnt give me 0 but the actual size of the list.

Comment: can anyone please help me out ??